# Can digital waveforms be transmitted through the air?

Tags: electromagnetism

If not what happens when data flows from a router to a laptop and back? I know that discontinuous waves require infinite bandwidth which is impossible. So, what is actually happening with wifi, or when music plays through a speaker without any wires?

Comment: *"I know that discontinuous waves require infinite bandwidth which is impossible."* - and yet...  [How to Key CW with raised cosine edges on the RF OUTPUT of any HAM RADIO RIG](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9J4eMRsGIQ)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about Information Technology and requires discussion of how digital protocols are defined.

Answer (score 1):

To transmit digital data, the signal does not have to be discontinuous: it only needs to make certain number of transitions per unit of time and these transitions could be quite smooth. So, although higher communication speeds generally require a higher bandwidth, it does not have to be infinite.

Comment: Also note that so-called digital signals are transmitted both through the air and via cables all the time, even on my computer as I type, and in the communication between the computer and the router.   One way is using the method described above, with a series of rapid transitions; if the duration exceeds the cutoff, you have a "1".  Another way is to use a voltage or light level, and just turn it on and off as the clock ticks.  In practical applications there are more sophisticated techniques: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulation#Digital_modulation_methods

Comment: Further, note that 'digital' signals in hardware are not discontinuous either - they are also just high frequency analog transitions that represent digital data. If you have ever seen how ugly signals on board a microprocessor are, you might consider it a minor miracle that they operate so well...

Comment: The thing is this:  in the signal processing context, a *digital signal* is a quantized, discrete time signal, i.e., a digital signal is *list* of numbers, taken from a finite set of finite precision numbers, that a computer can manipulate.  It is certainly true that a digital signal can be transmitted and received via some physical layer but, unless I'm mistaken, the physical layer involves *continuous* signals that are phase and amplitude modulated.  In other words, the physical layer representation of the digital signal isn't a quantized discrete time signal at all.  Just my two-cents FWIW.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mr. Centauri and others.  That helped. I don't believe my question is about information technology or about digital protocols exclusively.  I am talking about electromagnetism here. I am questioning how electric and magnetic fields interact to create wave forms that approximate digital data. From the evidence so far presented, it appears that the electromagnetic wave forms, which are analog are modulated and embedded with a small finite amount of digital markers that get extracted later.